# Sum of a vector of integers

Tags: c++

I created a program that let's the user input up to 10 integers and then it will print out the sum of the inputted integers. However I want to stop the program when the user tries to input more than 10 integers or when the user types in "DONE". I didn't really get it to work because when the user types in something other than an integer (including the string "DONE"), it will stop. I only want it to stop when the user types in "DONE". If the user types in something like "Hello" I want the program to crash.

This is how it should look:

```
Enter up to 10 numbers:

12
12
4
DONE

The sum of the integers is: 28
```

What's wrong with my code? I am referring to my void read_numbers function. As I mentioned, I want it to stop ONLY when the user inputs the string "DONE" or when the user inputs more than 10 integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Number_Type {
  vector<int> numbers;
};

void read_numbers(Number_Type& number) {
  int digit{};
  string line;
  // char space = ' ';

  while ((line != "DONE") && (number.numbers.size() != 10)) {
    cin >> digit;
    getline(cin, line);
    number.numbers.push_back(digit);
  }
}

int number_sum(Number_Type const& number) {
  int sum{};

  for (int i{}; i < number.numbers.size(); ++i) {
    sum += number.numbers[i];
  }

  return sum;
}

int main() {
  Number_Type number;
  cout << "Enter up to 10 numbers: " << endl;
  read_numbers(number);
  cout << "The sum of the integers is: " << number_sum(number);
}
```

Comment: Doing `cin >> digit;` and `getline(cin, line);` is performing two reads, and you don't check if the first read succeeds so you can perform error-handling if it doesn't. I'd suggest just doing the `getline`, then acting on the resulting string e.g. by comparing it to `"DONE"` and using [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: If there could be string in input, then you must input them all as strings and then check if it is a number or `DONE` or whatever else. Also to calculate sum of input you do not need to store all values.

Comment: @NathanPierson When I do:



`while ((line != "DONE") && (number.numbers.size() != 10))
{
getline(cin,line);
stoi(line);
number.numbers.push_back(line);

}`

I get errors saying that my "line" in my number.numbers.push_back(line) is a string and not an integer like my vector in Number_Type. But I used stoi(line) so then it would be an integer, right?

Comment: No. `stoi(line)` doesn't change `line`. Its _return value_ is the integer that's the result of the conversion.

Comment: @NathanPierson Hm I'm pretty lost on how to tackle this problem. I am using stoi(line) to covnert it to an integer.

Comment: Your code uses `stoi(line)` to convert `line` to an integer and then discards the results of the conversion. You'd want something like `int convertedLine = stoi(line); number.numbers.push_back(convertedLine);` or just `number.numbers.push_back(stoi(line));`

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes I already tried your solution, because I thought about that too but when I run the program and then type in "DONE" it will give me the following error:

 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi

Comment: First we need a function that implements a suitable deterministic crash. That is not easy to do in a portable way :-)

Answer (score 3):

Fist you have to read all your inputs as strings. Then you can use std::from_chars to check if your input was a valid integer (without having to do exception handling, which std::stoi will need). Example here (live demo https://onlinegdb.com/UANchB1mn)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <charconv>

auto read_numbers(const std::size_t max_numbers)
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    int value{};
    std::string input;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number " << values.size() + 1 << " of " << max_numbers << " (or DONE to stop) : ";
        std::cin >> input;

        // std::stoi is an option but then you would need do exception handling
        auto result = std::from_chars(input.data(), input.data() + input.size(), value);
        if (result.ec == std::errc())
        {
            values.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    while ((input != "DONE") && (values.size() < max_numbers));

    return values;
}

int main()
{
    auto values = read_numbers(3);

    std::cout << "you entered : ";
    for (const auto value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also decide whether you want user input like `123abc` to be treated as valid input, storing `123` in `values`, or invalid input to be error-handled in some fashion.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yup that too, didn't want to clutter up the example with too much parsing/errorhandling/reporting though. So on wrong input it will just ask for the same value again :)

Comment: This solution is probably great but a little too out of my comfort zone. Is there anyway my solution could be slightly modified for it to work? I tried doing stoi(line) to convert line to an integer but It didnt work:

When I do:

`while ((line != "DONE") && (number.numbers.size() != 10)) { getline(cin,line); stoi(line); number.numbers.push_back(line);  }`

I get errors saying that my "line" in my number.numbers.push_back(line) is a string and not an integer like my vector in Number_Type. But I used stoi(line) so then it would be an integer, right?

Comment: What part is out of your comfort zone? I can talk you through it :) You could do cin >> line; if(line != "DONE") { number.numbers.push_back(std::stoi(line)); }; however your code will be a more fragile and fail completely on input like "happy" because std::stoi will then throw an exception and my feeling was already that exception handling would be out of your comfort zone).

Comment: To be fair, in the question the intended behavior is for the program to crash on input that isn't `"DONE"` and can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes he did say that didn't he :) My brain must have filtered that out, "the program shall not crash (with uncaught exceptions) is high on my list of non-functional requirements :)

Comment: Yes, exceptions are necessary but I am taking on this task where we assume that the user only inputs DONE and not something else. 

When I tried following Nathans suggesiton:

`You'd want something like int convertedLine = stoi(line); number.numbers.push_back(convertedLine);`

The program compiles and runs but when I type in "DONE" it will crash giving the following errror:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi`

Comment: The exception is totally expected if you try to convert "DONE" to an int.
So that's why you need one extra if to check for "DONE" before calling std::stoi.

Comment: But have I not already done that in my loop: while (line != "DONE")
When I do getline and I type in DONE it shoudn't continue the loop. It should break.

Comment: No you first check for "DONE" then you ask for input so you will have to check again right after the std::cin.